# Understanding the solution of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation

> $\frac{dx}{dt} = \lambda x$

We have that general solution of this equation is:

> $x(t) = \pm e^{C}e^{\lambda t}$, for $C \in \mathbb{R}$

I'm having difficulty fully understanding the $\pm$ symbol in this solution. I can see that for any C, the function $x(t) =  e^{C}e^{\lambda t}$ solves the differential equation and the equation $x(t) = - e^{C}e^{\lambda t}$ also solves the differential equation. However my question is, for a given function $x(t)$ that solves this differential equation, do you have to 'fix' either a '+' or a '-' or would a function that, for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$, takes the value  $x(t) =  e^{C}e^{\lambda t}$ for some values of $\mathbb{R}$ and takes the value $x(t) = - e^{C}e^{\lambda t}$ for all other values of $\mathbb{R}$ also solve the equation?

Comment: $e^C$ can only take positive numbers, but the solution can also be negative. Even zero.And yes, you have to fix the sign.

Comment: You can write the solution of the DE as $x(t)=ce^{\lambda t}$ with $ c \in \Bbb{R}$ You need some intial condition to fix the value of the constant $c$.

Comment: Can you help me understand why you have to fix the sign? Wouldn't an equation that takes either the negative or positive value still satisfy the equation for any t?

Comment: I guess the $\pm$ comes from a prove involving $\ln$, right?

Comment: Try the intitial condition $x(0)=-1$ and also $x(0)=1$ what is the solution in these cases Brown ?

Comment: If the sign was not fixed the function would not be continuous, as $e^x>0$

Comment: Does a function to be differentiable require it to be continuous?

Comment: Yes, a function needs to be continuous to be differentiable, otherwise you run into *big* trouble (as for step functions). Physics do that all the time, but they have an instinct when this is possible and when not.

Comment: Thanks, if that's the case then it makes sense why you have to fix the sign. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

K.defaoite's answer explain clearly why you have the sign in front of the solution. Another way is to integrate the DE with integrating factor to avoid playing with the absolute value;
$$x'-\lambda x=0$$
$$x'e^{-\lambda t}- e^{-\lambda t }\lambda x=0$$
$$(e^{-\lambda t }x)'=0$$
After integration:
$$e^{-\lambda t }x=C$$
$$x(t)=Ce^{\lambda t }$$
With $C \in \Bbb {R}$

---

Or even more simple:
$$x'-\lambda x=0$$
Is a linear differential equation with constant coefficeints so that the characteristic polynomial is simply:
$$r-\lambda=0 \implies r= \lambda$$
The solution follows:
$$x(t)=Ce^{\lambda t}$$
With $C \in \Bbb {R}$

Comment: Good approach. Hadn't thought of doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks @K.defaoite.....

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity of the sign of the constant comes from an absolute value function we get from integration:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\lambda x$$
$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\int \lambda ~\mathrm{d}t$$
$$\ln|x|=\lambda t+c$$
This is where the sign problem happens. We can do a little algebra:
$$|x(t)|=e^{\lambda t}e^c=Ce^{\lambda t}$$
Because of the absolute value on the L.H.S, both $x(t)=Ce^{\lambda t}$ and $x(t)=-Ce^{\lambda t}$ satisfy the equation. Notice that $\pm C$ is actually significant, since $C$ is always a positive constant. One can even deduce
$$|x(0)|=Ce^{\lambda\cdot 0}=C\implies C=\pm x_0$$
If $x(t)$ starts negative, it will remain negative, and similarly for positive.

Comment: And you lost the solution where $x(t)=0$ in the first step.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Ok, but this is a degenerate "solution" and such cases are almost never considered when solving differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called eigenvalue problem. We normally simplify the solution by making $A=\pm e^{C}$. The differential equation shows that the derivative of x with respect to t is linear with respect to x. Since the exponential function behaves linearly with its derivative, thus, it is the general solution. Note that linear relation could be increasing (positive slop) or decreasing (negative slop), what makes the solution could be positive or negative. In conclusion, the differential equation descriptions two families of curves, the $A e^t$ and $-A e^{\lambda t}$ but never zero.